# contentbased String Matching

Tags: file, compare, string-matching

I tried to compare two text files and want to know how equal they are. The order of the words has to be considered.

For Example:

text_1:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo 
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
```

text_2:

```
Lorem ipsum sit amet, consictetuer 
adipiscing elit. Aenean dolor commodo 
ligvla eget dolor. massa.
```

I found lot of solutions to compare two text files line by line, but they give a dismatch in a line, if there is any difference. Like in the example all lines would be differ and I don't get any matches.

I need some Algorithm that compares the files **word by word**. It should see, that words within a line are equal and occurs in the same order, but sometimes maybe is a word missing, adding or a few characters doesn't match.

So the Algorithm shouldn't create a subsequent fault if one word is missing (like in the example: in text_2 is "dolor" missing, so if I compare the texts word by word in maybe an array I get subsequent faults for nearly the rest of the text)

My expected solution should give me:

- a list of words occure in both textes in the same context. [Lorem ipsum sit amet, adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo eget dolor. massa.]
- a list of words missed in the second text. [consectetuer, ligula, Aenean]
- a list of words added in the second text. [consictetuer, ligvla]
- a list of words that are in both texts, but on different positions [dolor]
- (optional) recognition of words that differ just in a few characters [ligula, ligvla]

The goal is to calculate a quantified grade of matching like 80% match. I don't know in detail how to calculate yet. But the main problem is to get the matches of words within a line if some words are missed or added [like the match of  "sit" "amet" in the first line in both texts.]

I started programming in java, but I switched to Perl because of the better handling of regex.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [I had a problem, so I decided to use regular expressions. Now I have 2 problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

Answer (score 0):

Also try [wdiff](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html#wdiff) particularly `-s` option

---

You can try to adapt some part of [Meld](http://meldmerge.org) algorithms to use words as a token instead of lines, but this task is barely has strong universal solution - that's why we see manual merge so often.

For example `one two three three two one` ~ `one two` - how would you tell which instance of "two" is left after edit? Or, maybe, only last "one" left after delete and then "two" was added to the end? The bigger the difference is, the bigger problems arise. But your particular data limitations and demands can render this pretty doable.